# Is there a way to prevent sources.list from having mixed release entries?

Tags: debian, apt

I used both `testing`, `buster` and I guess `sid` in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for a reason in the past and I turned my Debian into [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). As far as I could search the net, there were no possible way to recover it, so I reinstalled a Debian from scratch.

Is there a proven way to prevent me from doing such a mistake(!) in the future? For example, a trigger that will first check the `sources.list` to make sure that there are no mixed release entries before an update or install?

Comment: That has already been taken care of: normally, only root can change /etc/apt/sources.list.

Comment: That was funny :)

Answer (score 2):

`sources.list` is only modified manually.

Once upon a time `buster` was the codename for the `testing` suite.  If you installed `buster` during this time, you may have seen `testing`/`buster` as equivalent and arbitrarily used one or the other.  However, when `buster` became `stable`, and `testing` became `bullseye` you would have seen them diverge.

I've seen people make the same mistake, mixing the `stable` suite and the `stretch` codename.  This works as long as `stretch` is `stable`, but as soon as the transition happens, any sources with `stable` automatically upgraded to `buster`, while any sources with `stretch` remained at the same versions.

Here are some suggestions regarding when to use a codename versus a suite:

- Always use a codename (i.e. `buster`) instead of `stable`. The point of using a stable distribution is that `apt upgrade` carries no risk.  If you use `stable`, then you'll get a surprise every ~2 years.
- If you want a rolling distribution, use `testing`.  There is *some* risk every time you `apt upgrade`, but you'll be unaffected by the release cycle (some updates may be delayed during the freezes).
- If you are previewing the next release (i.e. Debian 11 bullseye), use the codename `bullseye`. You'll be on a rolling cycle (like testing) until that codename releases.  Then you'll be stable.  At my organization we use stable, but I always have a few machines pegged to the next release so we don't get surprises when we upgrade.

If you really want to protect yourself (maybe you have several `sudoers` on the machine), there are a couple of options:

1. apt.conf: In `/etc/apt.conf.d/00local` add:

```
APT::Default-Release "buster";
```

`man apt.conf` describes this as:

> Default release to install packages from if more than one version is available.
> Contains release name, codename or release version. Examples:
> 'stable', 'testing', 'unstable', 'buster', 'bullseye', '4.0', '5.0*'.

2. pinning:  I won't go into details here, but pinning is a very explicit way to force specific versions of specific packages. It can really mess up a system.  See `man apt_preferences` for details.

Comment: I added `/etc/apt/00local` file and changed the "release" portion of one entry (VirtualBox's) from buster to stretch and then tried to update with `apt-get update`. I expected apt to throw an error because `Default-Release` was `buster` but there were no errors and `apt-get update` finished as usual. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that there is no protection agains changes made by root to /etc/apt?  The fact that Stewart's answer isn't an answer to your question?  Funny, eh?  Seriously, I hope I'm mistaken but I'm afraid I'm not.  Again: if you have root permission, act accordingly. A production system might not be so easily reinstalled from scratch.

Comment: `Default-Release` doesn't create an error.  `Default-Release` simply means that if a package you are looking for exists in two sources (i.e. `buster` and `testing`) then it will take it from buster instead of taking the highest version number.

Comment: Also, IIRC (at least last time I checked) the virtualbox archive (not an official archives) only provides a `jessie` release.  If you use non-official sources, expect weirdness.

Comment: Also note that downgrading (i.e. `buster` to `stretch`) requires a pinning priority >1000 and I'm not sure that `Default-Release` provides that high of a priority.  Gerard is right... if you are trying to break your system, you can.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no setting to prevent updates depending on what is defined in `sources.list`. You can use [apt pinning](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html) to control the behavior of how packages are selected from multiple sources, including forcing packages to not be installed from specific sources.

Apt pinning allows you to set the priority of packages based on their name, source package name, version, or properties of the source repository they would be installed from. To see the current global priorities run `apt-cache policy`.

For example the following when placed into `/etc/apt/prefereneces/00default-release` will cause packages from buster, buster-updates, and buster-security to be preferred, Packages from buster-backports and non Debian sources will have their normal behavior. And finally any other packages from Debian sources will be uninstallable and removed if they are installed and not available from another source.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=buster,o=Debian
Pin-Priority: 990
Package: *
Pin: release n=buster-updates,o=Debian
Pin-Priority: 990
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

When bullseye is released you would edit your sources then edit that file to change `buster` to `bullseye` prior to upgrading.

I am currently using bullseye and have the following apt pinning configured. It makes bullseye packages from Debian preferred, followed by bullseye packages from third party sources, then any other packages from Debian except experimental. Finally all other packages would have their default priority of 500, followed by experimental with its default of 1.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=bullseye,o=Debian
Pin-Priority: 990
Package: *
Pin: release n=bullseye
Pin-Priority: 900
Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental
Pin-Priority: 1
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: 600
```

And finally the reason I do not use APT::Default-Release is because pinning gives more control. `APT::Default-Release "buster";` is just a shortcut to the following apt pinning entry.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=buster
Pin-Priority: 990
```